# how to print values in an array in order after sorted indexes in python?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

assume that i have 2 vectors, height and ages.

```
ages = np.random.randint(low=20, high=60, size=10)
heights = np.random.randint(low=150, high=200, size=10)
```

each value of age vector will corresponds to a height value. i want to print age and its corresponding height in order. i believe i have to sort the index of age first

```
a = np.argsort(ages)
```

and some how assign that index's order to age values. i thought about using loop but i don't know how? can someone please help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `np.argsort` function gives you the *indices* of the array in sorted order -- use the indices --

```
>>> ages = np.random.randint(low=20, high=60, size=10)
>>> heights = np.random.randint(low=150, high=200, size=10)
>>> ages
array([44, 35, 37, 39, 48, 24, 22, 25, 22, 59])
>>> heights
array([179, 195, 158, 189, 183, 185, 186, 187, 161, 175])
>>> ia = np.argsort(ages)
>>> ages[ia]
array([22, 22, 24, 25, 35, 37, 39, 44, 48, 59])
>>> heights[ia]
array([186, 161, 185, 187, 195, 158, 189, 179, 183, 175])
```

Note, in this case, you might consider a structured array:

```
>>> mytype = np.dtype([('age',int), ('height', int)])
>>> data = np.array(list(zip(ages, heights)), dtype=mytype)
>>> data
array([(44, 179), (35, 195), (37, 158), (39, 189), (48, 183), (24, 185),
       (22, 186), (25, 187), (22, 161), (59, 175)],
      dtype=[('age', '<i8'), ('height', '<i8')])
```

And now you can pass the "order" argument to `.sort`:

```
>>> data.sort(order='age')
>>> data
array([(22, 161), (22, 186), (24, 185), (25, 187), (35, 195), (37, 158),
       (39, 189), (44, 179), (48, 183), (59, 175)],
      dtype=[('age', '<i8'), ('height', '<i8')])
```

However, this isn't exactly equivalent as above, since it uses the height to break ties, so note, `(22, 161)` comes before `(22, 186)` here.

Comment: that is brilliant, i thought i have to use a loop to replace each index in age to sorted index and do the same with height

Comment: @EddieVu no, you almost never should have to loop. That's the whole point of numpy's vectorized operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pure python. If you have all unique values to be sorted, you can use a temporary dict:

```
ages = [2,4,1,6]
heights = [3,4,2,6]

temp = {}
for age, height in zip(ages, heights):
    temp[age] = height

for key in sorted(temp):
    print(key, temp[key])
```

If you have non-unique values then you can use a temporary array:

```
ages = [2,4,1,6,2]
heights = [3,4,2,6,7]

temp = []
for age, height in zip(ages, heights):
     temp.append((age, height))

for age, height in sorted(temp):
     print(age, height)
```